# MSChart does not show max labels

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, charts, mschart

I have to point out, that my chart is hosted in WPF, maybe it matters.

[image]

There is nothing fancy here.
Top AxisY label is not shown when I am explicitly setting Minimum and Maximum properties.
Right AxisX hides at random. For some data it is visible, for other not.

I just want to have chart without axis margins and show minimum and maximum labels on both axis.